# jQuery each function not working need to replace each attribute

Tags: jquery, each, attr, substr

I have this html

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="order" class="forms">
    <div>
        <span class="col1">Ref.</span>
        <span class="col2">Number</span>
        <span class="col3">Color</span>
        <span class="col4">Remarks</span>
        <span class="col5">Prijs</span>
    </div>
    <div class="order">
        <input type="text" name="ref-1" class="col1" />
        <input type="text" name="num-1" class="col2" />
        <input type="text" name="color-1" class="col3" />
        <input type="text" name="remark-1" class="col4" />
        <input type="text" name="price-1" class="col5" />
    </div>
    <a id="add" href="#">+</a>
</form>
```

And this jquery

```
$("#add").click(function() {     
    $("#order").children(":eq(1)").clone().each(function() {
            var index = $("#order").children().length - 1;
            alert(index);

        $(this).children().find(":input").each(function() {

                alert(index);

                    $(this).attr("[name]", function(i, v) {

                        return v.substr(0, v.lastIndexOf("-") + 1) + index;

                    }).val("");

                });
    }).insertBefore("#add");
});
```

I need to replace the -1 part of each input name to the incremented value.
But the js never gets to the `$(this).attr()` function
When I run this code it doesn't show the second alert box when I click `#add`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked the whole of  your code but there is a glaring error in that

```
.attr("[name]"
```

should be

```
.attr("name"
```

---

You also need to remove the `.children()` from the line

```
$(this).children().find(":input")
```

and make it

```
$(this).find(":input")
```

This is because `this` refers to the `div` element that contains the inputs. By running `.children()` on that it returns the `input` elements, and by doing `find()` on that it returns nothing, because find looks inside the selected elements, not-including the elements it runs on.

**updated jsfiddle** at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/TpmdP/

Comment: did you test this with my html? because now I get the second alert but it doesn't add the element I cloned. It's really weird

Comment: Oh I apologize I didn't check the jsfiddle link you gave. What's even more odd is that it works in your example but it doesn't in my code. Thanks for the example.

Comment: OK I know what my other problem was I still had the jquery 1.3.2 instead of jquery 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Remove .find(":input") and pass ":input" as argument to .children(). children() can retrieve child elements even by filtering the elements.